# Combinatorics: 30 people rotating around 6 tables - largest number of different people each person can meet?

Tags: combinatorics

Say there are 30 people at an event and six tables (A-F), each seating five people. There are six sessions, and each person must visit each table exactly once.

I /think/ that it's impossible for everyone to meet 24 different people under these conditions (because the number of tables isn't prime?), but is there an algorithm for working out the largest number of people each person can meet? I've tried various trial and improvement methods and am getting nowhere!

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: " impossible for no 2 people "...= possible for 2 people is it   ?

Comment: That seems to be for sure, since one can only meet a maximum of four new people per session, and there are only 6 sessions.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, that was another mistake. I meant 'impossible to meet 24 different people'.